# Python Pandas Merge only finds one match each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes, one has user monthly activity, the other has monthly fees and both have an ID number. I want to merge activity and fees in monthly rows.

```
all_dat = pd.merge(activity,fees,on=[id,year_month])
```

When I try to join them on the ID and time (datetime64), the result only has the first match for each user, with the date 2017-1-1.
Even though I can clearly find many identical datetimes in both dataframes, the merged one only gives me rows with 2017-1-1.

```
> print(set(all_dat[year_month]))
{Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')}
```

The fees frame looks something like this:

```
USER_ID   Name   Time       Fees
123       John   2016-12-01 300
123       John   2017-01-01 500
123       John   2017-02-01 400
```

And the activity one looks like this:

```
USER_ID   Name   Time       Activity
123       John   2017-01-01 20
123       John   2017-01-02 30
```

I would like to get something like this as a result of the merge:

```
USER_ID   Name   Time       Activity Fees
123       John   2017-01-01 20       500 
123       John   2017-01-02 30       400
```

But I only get the first match:

```
USER_ID   Name   Time       Activity Fees
123       John   2017-01-01 20       500
```

I don't think this is a dtype problem, what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of your dataframe and expected output please?

Comment: I've edited my question and described the situation and what I want, thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you try with a left join over the activity table?  all_dat = pd.merge(activity,fees,on=[id,year_month, how='left'])

Comment: Check for whitespace in your dataframe possible only on one record.  An easy way to do this is to use 'to_dict'.  fees_df.to_dict() and activity_df.to_dict().

Comment: @m33n it just gives me NaN for the data unless the date is 2017-01-01

Comment: Yeah, probably the time strings have some whitespace as @ScottBoston suggested. But I would simply apply rstrip() function over the 'Time' column and try with the left join again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I had the month and day in reverse order in each dataframe. Since the first of January is 01-01, it was the only one that got any matches. Make sure your datetime formats are uniform, folks.